# How to uninstall several applications using rpm -e?

Tags: fedora, uninstall, rpm

I'm a linux newbie using feodra 17.

I know I can uninstall something related to 'abcdef' like this:

> rpm -qa | grep 'abcdef'
>
> ...(lots of stuff relevant to 'abcdef')
>
> rpm -e (names listed above)

I want to know is there a convenient way to rpm -e (names above) automatically instead of inserting each name painstakingly by myself ?

Could anyone give an example ? I guess this can be done by using pipes or writing a script, but I need an example to tell me how to do this...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
yum remove *abcdef*
```